# Range of a projectile

Tags: kinematics, terminology, projectile

My notes say that the range of a projectile is equal to $$\sin(2\theta)(V_0^2/g) .$$ This equation implies that a ball shot at $0$ degrees has zero range but this isn't true is it? If I kick a football across the floor it still moves. What is the error in my reasoning?

Comment: There's no real error in your reasoning. But in the case of a projectile we assume it goes up and then comes back down. By that definition a horizontally fired projectile has zero range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The range of a projectile is defined as the point at which it first hits the ground.

If you kick a football across a flat floor, at a zero-degree angle, then it still moves ─ in continuous rolling contact with the floor. The range, as understood by your equation, is therefore zero.

Answer (score 0):

The equation that you've quoted assumed that the staring point and ending point are at the same height.

Furthermore this equation is only valid for air borne objects, not objects rolling on the ground.

If you launch a projectile at zero degrees from the horizontal you violate the conditions necessary for the equation to be valid.

You can derive the "range equation" for an arbitrary launch and terminate conditions and see that it is much more complicates but reduces to your equation in the right conditions.

If you launch a projectile at zero degrees then for it to be air born there cannot be a ground in the way for it to move and the problem can be solved using the original kinematics equations.  If there is a ground in the way then the ball will roll or skid on the ground and none of these equations hold.

So, in short you cannot just use equations outside of their realm of validity.